# Update column containing null

Tags: sql-server, null, sql-update

I am writing a very simple UPDATE query but it doesnt update `cardbalance` field.

```
update cardbalance
set CardBalance = CardBalance + 1000, TotalLoading= TotalLoading+356, Totalredemption = Totalredemption + 256 
where pan = '20000002'
```

I checked the `CardBalance` field and it was `NULL`. Is it because of this? Whats the solution?

Comment: yes, addition with NULL returns NULL

Comment: It means it was NULL before the update.  Check the insert.  Or add a 0 default value to the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  CardBalance is NULL then adding 1000 to it will give as NULL, so you may put an ISNULL to find if NULL and make it as 0(or something you want to).

```
 update cardbalance
 set CardBalance = ISNULL(CardBalance,0) + 1000, 
     TotalLoading= TotalLoading+356, 
     Totalredemption = Totalredemption + 256 
 where pan = '20000002'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE cardbalance
SET CardBalance = ISNULL(CardBalance,0) + 1000, TotalLoading= TotalLoading+356, Totalredemption = Totalredemption + 256 
WHERE pan = '20000002'
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add 1000 to a null value that is why it returns always null. use the ISNULL function to put a value of 0 when CardBalance is null. The query should be something like this:

```
update cardbalance
set CardBalance = isnull(CardBalance,0) + 1000, TotalLoading= TotalLoading+356, Totalredemption = Totalredemption + 256 
where pan = '20000002'
```